# How to get File Location using Jasny File Upload

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I wanted to pass the File Location to my Controller I have been using `data-bind ="value: x"` on each element here but to no available I can't catch the file location.

I'm using this script from Jasny Bootstrap FileUpload

```
<div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
  <div class="input-append">
    <div class="uneditable-input span3"><i class="icon-file fileupload-exists"></i> 
<span class="fileupload-preview"></span></div><span class="btn btn-file">
<span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
<input type="file" /></span><a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be helpful if you posted your entire form.
I have been struggling with the setup at first only to realize that all I had to do was set `:multipart => true` in the form.

```
<%= form_for @item, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
```

Once you do that, you should be able to get the file path in the controller.  I am not sure if that is a solution to your problem though.  Again, it would help if you showed more code and what you are currently getting in the params when you submit the form.

Comment: Hello Thanks for answering unfortunately we dont use forms as we use ajax calls to pass params to controller- so simply put that code was all it was.

Answer (score 0):

Check out same question with some answers on a different post:
[jQuery Ajax File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

The post by @Adeel solved my needs.